# create relative folder using c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Hello guys i am trying to create a folder using c# mvc3. I have the following code in my controller

```
string path = Path.Combine("~/Content/albums", album.title.Replace(" ", ""));
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

but it does not seem to create a folder. I have tried using directory without relative paths and it works

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("c:/test");
```

Thank you

Comment: What's inside path when you try this?

Comment: You need to have assigned appropriate permissions for the ASP.Net application to be able to read and write to the directory. Secondly look at HttpServerUtility.MapPath to find out about application paths. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx

Comment: hmm "~/Content/albums\\gone" gone is the title of the album @SimonEdström

Comment: That dosn't sound like a valid path ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the Server.MapPath (if in the Controller) or System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath (if outside the Controller) first on the Content, it maps the virtual resource path to the physical path,
so:

```
string contentPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/albums");
string path = Path.Combine(contentPath, album.title.Replace(" ", ""));
```

And then create the directory.

Answer (score 2):

Try this insteed, as you point out it's not a valid path you have.

```
 string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/albums");
 string path = Path.Combine(physicalPath , album.title.Replace(" ", ""));

 Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```